# Can Sphinx accidentally 'cache' conf files?

Tags: sphinx

I have an index I rotate as I make changes to the table or conf which had an associated wordform file where I created a wordform to map among other things:

```
Ft > Fort
```

I ended up removing that from the workdform and re-rotating and re-rotated successfully yet when I search on `FT` I still find `Fort`. I then commented out the wordform

```
#wordforms = /home/...
```

and rotated successfully and still `FT` finds `Fort`.

Lastly I changed the name of the wordform file and, you guessed it, after rotating it still finds `Fort`.

Is there some way this has cached the old index as no matter what I do it finds the old wordmap and uses it?

Comment: by rotate you also include reindexing? Once index config is changed and you issue an indexing, the indexing will use the changed config. Perhaps indexing is done, but rotation fails for some reason (check index files timestamps or the logs/output of indexer )

Comment: Also double check the document that contains 'Fort', doesnt actully contain FT **somewhere**. Maybe in some other field. Its easy to misdiagnose issues like this. ie running a searching 'FT', is not because of the wordform, but because the document still matches FT directly.

Comment: @barryhunter It turns out I had to restart sphinx and then rotate, for some reason it was not (there had been a server error prior). Once I did so the Ft/Fort issue was solved.

Comment: @aditirex Hmm. Right now my workflow is if I change the config i simply rotate the index and that has worked fine. Are you saying there is another step I need to take as well? As per my reply to BarryHunter above, I restarted Sphinx and then rotated and it worked fine.

Comment: You shouldnt need to restart sphinx. But if for some reason if indexer is unable to send the signal to searchd, it might not automatically reload. (say searchd is running as root, and indexer a less privleged user)